# Sonar exclusion properties is not picking up during scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I'm trying to run sonar scanner from jenkins by cloning the source code from the Github repo.

Usecase: while running the sonar scanner I don't want to include some of the project directories to be a part of the scan.

To which I've added the following properties in order:

```
Sonar.projectkey= Sonar.projectversion= Sonar.projectname= Sonar.sources= X, x/y, x/z Sonar.exclusions= x/a/**
```

After running the sonar scanning with the above results, I came to know that the scan is still picking up the code from the x/a/** directories. Please suggest any inputs If I'm missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
sonar.exclusions=x/a/**
```

without blank:

```
Sonar.exclusions= x/a/**
```

if you want to run on command line, it should be :

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=x/a/**
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried doing the same without the spaces. But landed with no luck

Comment: for comand line, it should be : `-Dsonar.projectkey= -Dsonar.projectversion= -Dsonar.projectname= -Dsonar.sources= X, x/y, x/z -Dsonar.exclusions= x/a/**`